# Given a complex number $\omega=\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics, solution-verification, factoring

I'm given that complex number and I'm asked to calculate $\omega^5$, which I guess it's $\left(e^{2i\pi/5}\right)^5=e^{2i\pi}=1$. Then, I have to prove $1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4=0$. I've done it like that:

$$\omega·(1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4)=\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4+\omega^5=1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4$$

Therefore, since $\omega\neq 1$, we have $1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4=0$.

Now I'm asked to find a quadratic equation with integer coefficients with roots $\omega+\omega^4$ and $\omega^2+\omega^3$. Here is my try:

$$(x-(\omega+\omega^4))·(x-(\omega^2+\omega^3))=(x-\omega-\omega^4)(x-\omega^2-\omega^3)$$

Since $-\omega^2-\omega^3=1+\omega+\omega^4$,

$$(x-\omega-\omega^4)(x+\omega^4+\omega+1)=x^2+x-2-\omega-\omega^2-\omega^3-\omega^4=0$$

Therefore, the quadratic equation would be $x^2+x-1=0$. Is there any mistake? I'm not sure about my answer.

Comment: It's correct. ${}{}{}$

Comment: It all looks correct to me also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have written a perfectly valid proof. Just note that the general case is also true (and pretty important as well). Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and consider the complex $n$th root of $1$, i.e., the complex number $\omega_n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ that satisfies the equation $z^n=1$. Of course there are $n$ solutions to this equation, we take $\omega_n$ as the one with the minimal argument (except from $1$). The calculation of $\omega_n^n$ is as you have done - using de Moivre formula, $\omega_n^n=(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}})^n=e^{2\pi i}=1$.

By the sum of a geometric sequence (which is also true for complex numbers), we know that
$$1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^{n-1}=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1},$$
and therefore plugging in $z=\omega_n$ yields zero in the RHS, and the sum you were requested to calculate in the LHS.

Comment: Woah, amazing explanation. I'm not even in university yet so I'm still not used to generalise much. Just one question, is the equation z^n the same as ω^n but generalized for all complex numbers?

Comment: @albertvvila you mean the equation $z^n=1$? It is like the equation $x^n=1$ for all the real numbers (denoted $x\in\mathbb{R}$). However in the real numbers we might sometimes have only one solution ($x=1$ is always a solution); the general set of $n$ complex solutions to the equation $z^n=re^{i\phi}$ for some given $re^{i\phi}\in\mathbb{C}$ (where $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers) is $z_k=\sqrt[n]{r}e^{i(\frac{ϕ}{n}+\frac{2πk}{n})}$, where $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: I'm having some issues in the next part of the exercise. I'm asked to prove, with the quadratic equation I obtained, that $cos(2π/5)=(-1+\sqrt5)/4$. I tried to represent it on an Argand diagram to get some idea, but I don't really know how to prove it.

Comment: Note that $(\cos(\frac{2\pi k}{5})+i \sin(\frac{2\pi k}{5}))^{5}=(-1)^k.$ Using the binomial theorm, $(x+y)^{5}=x^5+5x^4y+10x^3y^2+10x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5$, the imaginary part of the previous expression is $\sin^5(\pi k/5)-10\sin^3(\pi k/5)\cos^2(\pi k/5)+5\sin(πk/5)\cos^4(πk/5)=0$, and since $\sin^2(\pi k/5)=1-\cos^2(\pi k/5)$ we obtain $16 \cos^4⁡(πk/5)-12\cos^2⁡(πk/5)+1=0.$ The solutions for this equation are $±(1±√5)/4$, and from here you can deduce (for $k=2$) that $\cos⁡(2π/5)=(-1+√5)/4$.